# Changing the delimiter in a text file with php

Tags: php, delimiter

I found on the forum the following script which is simple and works fine for me.
The problem is that the source file is a PHP file with a verticla bar delimiter "|" and I want the downloaded result to become a CSV file, replacing the "|" with a "," so that when the file is saved, it can be opened with Excel.
Will appreciate your help
Thanks

```
<?php
    $local_file = 'memberslogin.php';
    $download_file = 'memberslist.php';

    // set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
    $download_rate = 20.5;
    if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file))
    {
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
        header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

        flush();
        $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
        while(!feof($file))
        {
            // send the current file part to the browser
            print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
            // flush the content to the browser
            flush();
            // sleep one second
            sleep(1);
        }
        fclose($file);}
    else {
        die('Error: The file '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace("|", ",", $some_string);` will replace all occurences of '|' by ',' in "$some_string".

If writing from scratch I'd do it differently; but as the code in your qn works you could try replacing the "print fread" line with this one:

```
print str_replace("|", ",",fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024)));
```

Its a long time since I've used excel, but if the download is for your own use you could alternatively import the file specifying "|" as your delimiter. I do remember that downloads/imports can be problematic if cells contain quote marks.

Comment: Thanks scytale, My initial thought was to split it into 2 steps, do the conversion first and only download the result, but I like your suggestion better and it works OK. I am controlling the data input and strip off any commas before saving it to the database. The club treasurer is an older guy, not very computer literate and didn't understand when I told him how to handle the "|" seprated file. I am intrigued to see if you can offer a better way to do this job... Cheers